# Wordpress: load a page at the bottom of another page

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to create a way that takes me from one page to another in wordpress without reloading the page.
Let me explain better, I would like that at the bottom of "Page 1" there is a button that leads to "Page 2", by **clicking** the **button** I would like "**Page 2**" **to appear directly without having to reload the page** and that "Page 1" is no longer present at the top of the page.

I saw the effect by visiting this page, at the bottom there is the "Next project" button that directly loads the next page without changing the page, hiding the current page.

https://www.aquest.it/en/cecchi

I'm using **Wordpress** platform so I would need a compatible solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you exactly asking ? if it's possible ? Or are you asking for a solution ? In the second case you should provide what you've tried so far, your research efforts and what is your specific issue. Otherwise it will look like you are asking us to do your job, which is not the purpose of SO. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49777354/edit) your question to make it better.

Comment: I asked what techniques could be used to achieve my purpose. I spent a lot of time looking for online forums, without finding an answer. Now I will try with Suraj's advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using ajax request code thorough some jquery on you current page.
Let me explain in brief.

1) first on button click you need to write a function in jquery in which you need to pass next page url and all the other things in ajax request.

2) you will get all the code in ajax response from next page.

3) once you get all the data in ajax response you need to remove the first page data through jquery or javascript and after that append next page data on same page again with jquery or javascript.

In short you need to do know what jquery and ajax request and how they work in getting the next page data on current page.

Hope it will help you.:)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try to try my hand at these new techniques and see if I can make it work!